# Como ordenar alfabeticamente e numericamente uma mesma lista?

Tags: java, classificação, collection

No meu trabalho de faculdade eu devo fazer uma lista do tipo de uma classe que eu criei e devo ordená-la de duas formas diferentes, uma por ordem alfabética e outra por pontuação média. Além disso outra informação é que a ordenação alfabética não deve ser padrão, mas a de pontuação média deve ser.

Assim eu pesquisei sobre a interface `Comparable`, não sei se estou no caminho certo estudando isso, porém eu não consegui o que eu queria, pois o `Comparable` serve só pra um `compareTo()`.

Então como eu faço para ordenar essa lista dessas duas formas com só um método de ordenação? Se possível gostaria um exemplo.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Nos mostre o código que fez até agora, sem ele fica difícil analisarmos o problema para saber se você está indo no caminho certo ou não. Aqui no site preferimos perguntas objetivas, então tente moldar muito bem seu problema, caso contrário, a pergunta pode ser suspensa por ser muito ampla.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você está a procura da interface `Comparator`. Essa interface te dá a possibilidade de ordenar uma coleção de inúmeras maneiras diferentes. A vantagem dela sobre o `Comparable` é que você não precisa modificar a classe cujo objetos você deseja ordenar, portanto pode usá-la inclusive em classes que não são modificáveis.

Suponha a classe `Pessoa`:

```
class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private float peso;
    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade, float peso) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.peso = peso;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }
    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    public float getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }
    public void setPeso(float peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pessoa [nome=" + nome + ", idade=" + idade + ", peso=" + peso + "]";
    }
}
```

Ela possui três atributos diferentes e você quer ordenar uma lista de objetos do tipo `Pessoa` cada hora usando um dos atributos. Você precisará criar uma classe para cada atributo que deseja usar como base na comparação, assim:

```
class OrdenaPorNome implements Comparator<Pessoa> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pessoa um, Pessoa dois) {
        return um.getNome().compareTo(dois.getNome());
    }
}

class OrdenaPorIdade implements Comparator<Pessoa> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pessoa um, Pessoa dois) {
        return um.getIdade() - dois.getIdade();
    }
}

class OrdenaPorPeso implements Comparator<Pessoa> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pessoa um, Pessoa dois) {
        if(um.getPeso() > dois.getPeso()) return 1;
        if(um.getPeso() < dois.getPeso()) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Ao criar uma classe que implementa o `Comparator` você é obrigado a implementar o método `compare()` cujo os argumentos esperados são do tipo genérico informado entre os `<>`. Repare que a implementação que eu fiz acima envolve três tipos diferentes: uma `String`, um `int` e um `float`.

Para o `String` eu usei o próprio método `compareTo()` que a classe implementa. Para o `int` eu subtraí um pelo outro. Para o `float` eu fiz as comparações necessárias para retornar um valor coerente, pois não é possível fazer a subtração pois o método espera como retorno um `int` e teríamos problemas com o arredondamento.

Agora é só por tudo isso para rodar:

```
public class Comparando {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Pedro", 25, 71));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Maria", 27, 60));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa("João", 30, 75.5f));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Fernanda", 40, 55));        

        System.out.println("Ordenando por nome:");
        Collections.sort(pessoas, new OrdenaPorNome());
        System.out.println(pessoas);

        System.out.println("Ordenando por idade:");
        Collections.sort(pessoas, new OrdenaPorIdade());
        System.out.println(pessoas);

        System.out.println("Ordenando por peso:");
        Collections.sort(pessoas, new OrdenaPorPeso());
        System.out.println(pessoas);
    }
}
```

Saída:

> Ordenando por nome:
>   [Pessoa [nome=Fernanda, idade=40, peso=55.0], Pessoa [nome=João, idade=30, peso=75.5], Pessoa [nome=Maria, idade=27, peso=60.0], Pessoa [nome=Pedro, idade=25, peso=71.0]]
>
> Ordenando por idade:
>   [Pessoa [nome=Pedro, idade=25, peso=71.0], Pessoa [nome=Maria, idade=27, peso=60.0], Pessoa [nome=João, idade=30, peso=75.5], Pessoa [nome=Fernanda, idade=40, peso=55.0]]
>
> Ordenando por peso:
>   [Pessoa [nome=Fernanda, idade=40, peso=55.0], Pessoa [nome=Maria, idade=27, peso=60.0], Pessoa [nome=Pedro, idade=25, peso=71.0], Pessoa [nome=João, idade=30, peso=75.5]]

Comment: obrigado, era o que eu queria, mas eu queria saber também o que seria ordenação default e uma não default que o meu problema fala?

Comment: Por ordenação default da String eu entendo que é organizar de A a Z, a não default seria qualquer critério de organização diferente disso, como por exemplo ordenar de Z a A. Para fazer assim basta trocar a ordem das variáveis dentro do método `compare()`